# WPF Grid vs HTML Div, Is it possible to prevent controls overlap?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In WPF, I have this simple Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Firstlabel" />
    <Label Content="Secondlabel" />
</Grid>
```

and when I run it , they both are placed right on top of each other so you can't see the SecondLabel, only FirstLabel is visible.

Now , obviously I am not using any margins,or dockpanel/stackpanel/Wrappanel.

I would have thought that like HTML Divs ( I know , comparing apples & oranges), the SecondLabel will simply be put **next**to the FirstLabel, leaving both visible.

So one **must**use a layout container in this situation or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you *must* use a layout container. However, `Grid` is also a layout container. If you don't want to use a `StackPanel` or any other control which behaves like you described, you can also define rows and columns inside of a `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Firstlabel" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Content="Secondlabel" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

You can also set the width of the `RowDefinition`.

Comment: I think this is just the default behaviour( the overlapping) .thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for, are the columndefinitions:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Label Content = "FirstLabel" Grid.Column="0" />
 <Label Content = "SecondLabel" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.